# Adding Currency Switcher in header

Tags: template, xml, currency

I've been following this tutorial to add currency switcher to header of my magento theme:
http://www.jimcode.org/2011/02/magento-multi-language-currency-region-setup/

I've add currency block and others under header of my page.xml file:

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
    <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
    <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
    <block type="directory/currency" name="currency" as="currency" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
</block>
```

then under header.phtml file under my template, I've added these lines:

```
         <div class="span2 offset1 flags-wrapper">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
          </div>

          <div class="span1 f-select-wrapper">
              <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency'); ?>
              <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_switcher') ?>
          </div>
```

Store language is appearing fine, while neither store views, nor currency views are displaying on the header.

Please help me point out what am i missing.

Comment: Just to make sure you covered this: Do you have at least 2 currencies and at least 2 store views enabled on your website?

Comment: Yes this is what I was missing. I've added 2-3 currencies using this tutorial, and it worked like a charm:
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/
If you could add this suggestion, as an answer rather than comment, I'll mark that as correct.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currency switcher appears only if you have at least 2 currencies enabled.
Same goes for language/store view switcher. It appears only if you have at least 2 active store views on your website.

Comment: I have two languages and 2 currencies setup. The home page only has language selector showed up, not the currency selector

Comment: I have same issue ...u got solution?